# How can I copy from another sheet for the cells if they are only blank?

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I want to compare two sheets and if the row in `sheet1` empty, then copy the same row from `sheet(project)`.

My goal is to copy the new entries at Column A from `sheet("Project")` to `sheet1` BUT only the new entries!

For example in `sheet1` `A1:A20` already not blank. In `sheet("project")`, `A1:A27` are NOT Blank.

I want to copy the last 7 cells.

The code I wrote copies all the rows. I want to copy the rows which if they are blank in `sheet1`, then copy those rows from `sheet(project)`.

```
Sub CopyD()

    Dim lst As Long

    Sheets("Project").Select

    Range("A1:A10000").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.Copy

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lst = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & lst).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .Range("A" & lst).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Copy pasting a range from 1 sheet to another is very fast. So how does it make a difference? Simply copy `A1:A27` and paste over `A1:A20` :) It is max 2 lines of code (depending on how you want to copy)

Comment: No, but I want to do it dynamically:

I want to run macro to create reports. This was just a small sample to depict what I need. Think that I have 8 columns from 55 columns to copy, and each column will be another column in my report.

Comment: Run your code step by step and tell us what is the exact issue that you are facing, then we can help you.

Comment: Can you amend your question with the exact requirement. Be as descriptive as possible. Use screenshots to show sample data if you want. This way we can give you an exact reply :)

Comment: @RaunakThomas I am so novice that I do not even know how to run and show here.

Comment: Are the new rows always at the bottom? In that case what you want is to copy all rows in sheet(project) that have a row number greater than the largest occupied row in sheet1?

Comment: @HarassedDad Yes, new rows always are greater than the sheet1

Comment: To check if Row `lst` is empty, you can use `Application.Counta(.Rows(lst))` - if it's >0 then there is data in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopyNewRows

Dim x as long
dim y as long
with worksheets("Sheet1")
x = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row  'last occupied row in col A
end with
with  worksheets("Project")
y =.cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'last occupied row in source sheet
.range(.cells(x+1,1),.cells(y,1)).entirerow.copy worksheets("sheet1").cells(x+1,1)
end with
end sub
```

This assumes that column A is always filled for each occupied row

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
However,

x = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup)

Why do you think that I get  `run time error 13`?

Comment: It's assuming there is data in sheet1 - if there isn't anything there - or the sheet isn't actually called sheet1 - it would get an error.

Comment: 'x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)   'last occupied row in col A

is the error, why is that?